# Firebase Syntax with Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

Here is some Firebase related code taken from an iOS app of mine:

```
var dataRef = firebaseRootReference?.child(byAppendingPath: "MyList")
dataRef = dataRef?.child(byAppendingPath: key)

dataRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
    .......
    }, withCancel: { error in
        print(error.description)
})
```

The above code was working fine. But I just upgraded my project to Swift 3.0 and I now get this error message:

> Cannot convert value of type '(_) -> ()' to expected argument type '((Error?) -> Void)!'

Browsing the net I can only find examples of similar code without error handling part.
If I just comment out one part like below, I get rid of the error but I doubt this is the right solution.

```
var dataRef = firebaseRootReference?.child(byAppendingPath: "MyList")
dataRef = dataRef?.child(byAppendingPath: key)

dataRef?.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
    .......
    }/*, withCancel: { error in
        print(error.description)
}*/)
```

What is the right way to write the code above in Swift 3.0 ?

Comment: `child(byAppendingPath: "MyList")` has been deprecated in Swift 3, replace with `child("MyList")`

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error because of line `print(error.description)`. [`Error`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/error) protocol doesn't have property `description`, simply changed it with `localizedDescription` will solve your problem.

```
print(error.localizedDescription)
```

The whole code will be like below.

```
dataRef?.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

    //get data from snapshot object
}, withCancel: { error in

    print(error.localizedDescription)
})
```